# Installing of .net framework 4 after installing plesk 11

Tags: windows, plesk, .net-framework-version

I have a windows 2008 server with plesk 11.
I installed plesk and after adding few hosts I realized that .Net 4 is missing so I download and Installed .Net 4 but now Plesk does not have .Net 4 in host configuration and I don't know How I can tell Plesk to update its database and allow me to select .net 4 for my hosts.

Comment: Sounds like a plesky problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try "Refresh" at "Tools & Settings \ Server Components"